# Is there a way to force gradle to compile c++ code(and only it) for only 1 project at a time?

Tags: c++, jenkins, gradle

We have a couple of independent projects building with gradle through jenkins pipeline and compiling some c++ code as a part of gradle job. We use vc17.
 By building them alltogether in parallel we sometimes get related problems of corrupted files(too often to neglect). 
 **Is there a way to force c++ code compile for only 1 gradle job at a time?**
 Preferably as fast as it can be done i.e. not cutting workers or threads or other resources for this particular code compiling.

PS: I know i can block some jenkins builds while running others but that's far from optimal - each jenkins job completes in 1-2 hours, and gradle takes only about 2/3 of it, about 2/3 time of which takes in turn c++ code compiling

Comment: If parallel builds create 'corrupted files', they're not really independent, are they? I suggest you sort out the cause of this corruption (typically it's intermediary files that get stomped on) by extracting the stompy bits and introducing a dependency

Comment: Well, the sources are independent, but compilers and builders are common and that's where the problem lies

Comment: *but compilers and builders are common and that's where the problem lies* - most likely not

Comment: you can probably wrap the compiler in some script file, which will first acquire some "lock", and release it after it is done, but depends what precisely is causing the corruption, if it's just two compiler instances running at the same time, or it's the build-cache sharing between compiler instances (then if such locked wrapper will interleave building between two jobs, you may still end with corrupted files). Also I'm not Jenkins expert, but isn't there some way to isolate the build dirs of the different jobs (including internal caches of VC17)? I would actually expect that to be default...

Comment: projects isolated but compiling goes at the same time so it's couple of instances running along

Comment: Well gradle is a wrap around c++ compiler. I thought about lock and all but i found that it locks only compiling project but not compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Build a structure of dependencies in Gradle, where projects are referred to via `dependsOn`. (As @Botje points out - your projects do not seem to be independent.)

Say you have a `projectA` which depends on prior finished compilation of `projectB`. You have also a `projectC`, which depends on `projectA` and `projectB` to complete in order B > A > C.

You can make compilation of C dependent on A, B, by declaring for the compilation task of C in Gradle:

```
dependsOn( projectACompilationTask )
dependsOn( projectBCompilationTask )
```

To ensure proper order of A, B you can then define for the `projectCCompilationTask`:

`tasks.findByName('projectACompilationTask').mustRunAfter 'projectBCompilationTask'`

You will also have to define the compilation tasks I described here. You can use for example tasks to trigger CMake or whatever you use currently to initiate compilation.

Comment: There is no dependencies between projects. They run in different workspaces, they are isolated. They use same build script provided through shared libraries but the problems only appears when gradle builds code via cmake. Gradle have similar but different configs.

Comment: And if you suggest me to manually write an order in which those jobs will be building - that is no good

Comment: Why would that be? If you don't want an order of the full build pipeline you can still introduce an order of C++ compilation, ensuring a compilation happens only after another compilation. Or you can use configuration tasks to set what build you want to do, then make sure to only execute one pipeline at a time.

If all you need to know if Gradle has some internal flag which tells it not to compile more than one C++ codebase at a time - no, there is no such thing. You need to get clear on what you need exactly and then implement the build pipeline accordingly.

Comment: Sounds to me as if you need to rework your entire pipeline architecture. You claim there are no dependencies between the projects, yet you also claim files get corrupted when you compile multiple C++ instances at once. Makes no sense to me, see what @Botje mentioned.

Comment: Well.. i prefer not to rewrite each conifg every time new similar project appears. What i want is some sort of lock which prevents other codebase to compile while 1 runs. If c++ compiler and gradle doesn't have solutions i'll try to make one through pipeline.

Comment: For now i blocked these builds so they could only run 1 at a time. And I don't know exactly why but i see where those problems appears - in lib linking process and only with nightly builds which runs all at the same time. I suspect hardware problems. But while im looking for solution i need to  make them build up as fast as possible because there are other builds too which working fine

Comment: Maybe compiler shares some folders among compilation processes in order for files to become corrupted. One other idea for you could be the following: You could call the C++ compiler via bash/batch. The compiler returns a value when it is done and you can store a default value globally. So when the script is called, the compiler variable must be checked and if a compilation is already taking place, then the next compilation must be queued. Again, there is a ton of ways to do this, not sure which works best for you.